# Create (.ics) file so that TimeZone transfer is ignored by outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, icalendar

We are writing a c# server to generating the .ics files which would be shared by people from different timezones. We have one requirement says if the people in Sydney open the file the event says 9:30pm. The people in Perth should also see it as 9:30pm. i.e. No auto timezone offset applied the calendar by outlook.

I have looked many places and yet to find a solution.

Is that possible?

Comment: "9:30 am [...] 9:30pm". I assume that's a typo?

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake of me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this really makes sense in terms of what an ics file represents - it's an invitation to an event, where "an event" is a thing which happens at a specific time. If something's happening at 09:30 in Sydney, then it's not happening at 09:30 in Perth so it can't be the same event. Sounds to me like you need to create multiple events, one for each timezone.

Comment: I know and totally agree with you mate, but what is asked is what need to been done here. I think probably I need to create different files and put logic to detect user's locale or timezone.

Comment: This is incorrect. iCalendar supports the notion of 'floating times' which is _exactly_ what typingpanda is looking for.

However, I'm not sure if it works in outlook.